# Handle recursive Json after migration from EF Core 6 to EF Core 8

Tags: c#, json, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Using .Net 6, we've been storing some data in json columns.
To do it, we've encapsulated a class inside a `documentClass`, that allow us to extract some data if needed.
In .Net 6, we simply had to declare the column as jsonb, and a `TypeHandlerResolverFactory` to handle the serialisation.

We're looking to migrate to .Net 8, and to use the integrated json support from EF Core 8, and it require to map the navigation property inside the Json.
Most of the time it's ok for us to do so, but we got some class with recursive calls and we don't know how to declare it.
As we don't need to query it, we've tried to simply ignore the property, but doing so also ignore it for serialisation.

Here is an exemple class :

```
    public class FooDocument
    {
       public Guid Id { get; set; }
       public Foo Raw { get; set; }
    }
    public class Foo
    {
      public List<Foo> Childs { get;set; }
    }
```

And the basic mapping

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FooDocument>().OwnsOne(
    post => post.Raw, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
    {
        ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
        ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(metadata => metadata.Childs);
    });
```

Then I got an error because EF don't manage to determine the owner for the relationship.

Is there a way to do it easily, for exemple by telling EF I don't plan to query this so it simply have to serialize the class ?
As we've several class concerned, we'ld rather find a generic way to handle it.

Comment: Try remove `OwnsMany` line.